# Erro de conexão com sqlserver ao edicionar o Connection Timeout na connectionString

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tenho uma WebApi onde preciso buscar a quantidade de registros de uma determinada tabela no sqlexpress no servidor de produção, local não tenho problemas nenhum.

Estou usando `ADO` puro e com `ExecuteScalar`, sem nenhum ORM, tenho recebido erros de timeout, que consegui pegar a Exception através de logs.

Tentei aumentar o Connection `Timeout=120`, mas basta eu colocar o parâmetro na minha connectionstring, com qualquer valor de timeout, que recebo o erro abaixo no log que mandei gravar:

> **A entrada 'Context' já foi adicionada. (C:\inetpub\WebAPI\apiv2\web.config line 73)**

Minha string de conexão esta assim:

```
<add name="Context" connectionString="data source=CLIENTE-XXXXX\SQLEXPRESS2014; initial catalog=BaseInventario;  user id=UsuarioXXX;Password=XXXXX; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Connection Timeout=30"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Pela mensagem, parece que eu inseri duas vezes a string de conexão, mas não fiz isso, o erro só acontece quando coloco o parâmetro de timeout, ao remover o erro para de acontecer.

Alguem tem idéia do motivo desse erro?

Segue abaixo meu método que esta dando timeout

```
public int GetTotalPorInventarioData(int InventarioId, int idPatrimonio, DateTime DataAtualizacao)
        {
            int retorno = 0;
            try
            {
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Context"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    String sql = @"SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM Inventarios.Patrimonios WITH (NOLOCK) where InventarioId = " + InventarioId + " and (DataUltimaAtualizacao >= @DataConsultar or DataUltimaAtualizacao is null) and Id >= " + idPatrimonio;
                    retorno = conn.ExecuteScalar<int>(sql, new { DataConsultar = DataAtualizacao });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return retorno;
        }
```

Comment: Coloque um <clear /> antes na linha de cima da connection string e verifica se resolve seu problema.

Comment: poste o código para ajudarmos. assim não da pra ajudar muito

Comment: Obrigado wallafe, adicionei o codigo...  ele é bem simples e direto "acho", existem outros que retornam lista que também dão timeout.
Suspeito de alguma configuração no SQLServer, mas não encontrei nada que pudesse causa isso.

Comment: Coloquei a tag  <clear /> que o George Wurthmann, o erro "A entrada 'Context' já foi adicionada..." parou de ocorrer, mas o erro de timeout continuou acontecendo...

Comment: Cara, a mensagem é clara... Você está adicionando mais de uma vez a chave da Context em seus arquivos de configuração ou ainda criando uma nova em conexão em runtime... Outro ponto a obserar é porque você está recebendo timeout em consultas tão simples. Você precisa rever a estrutura do seu banco, tipagem, índices e etc